# Apache android output considered as PUP.HighConfidence

Tags: android, cordova, virus

I've created a simple hello cordova application by running command:

```
cordova create test
```

then I build android so I can have `android-debug.apk` in output folder, but the problem is when I scan it with [Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/af10e371c76438db65b482f2897425d61b78d33cfd36b8c997ee9abddd9e52ca/detection) `WhiteArmor` issues `PUP.HighConfidnce` on my app.
Is there anything wrong with my app or this is because of cordova's [bundled](https://www.bitdefender.com/support/what-is-a-pua-pup-software-1189.html) stuff?

BTW, is there anyway to get over it?

Comment: I think you should bikhial these dam things and keep going on `react` and `react-native`. :D

Comment: @AmerllicA Yeah that's the answer (but won't be accepted, lol). BTW this question has been asked almost a year ago, but thanks for the time.